# Google Chrome's Back button is basically broken

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I click the Back button in Chrome, it just does round and round, and does not bring me back. My history is fine. What could have caused this?

**Edit:** It seems to have a problem with Superuser.com and all the stack-exchange sites ,in particular...

Comment: Does it do this on every page every time?  What exactly do you mean by "just does round and round"?

Comment: Its like its loading, but never actually loads the page, or even the URL.

Comment: Clean all your cache and try again. Also, does this happen for every site?

Comment: Mostly seems like superuser, but im sure there are more. Cache clearing did nothing

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you hit the backspace key?  Superuser also uses a lot of JS/Ajax, but you shouldn't run into any issues with the latest version of Chrome...

Comment: Yes. it does, no change

Comment: and the other stack-exchange sites? and does this happen each and every time??

Comment: Yes, but its intermittent for all of them. I dont think that my browser has something agianst SE

Answer (score 2):

I had this happening as well.  It appears that disabling all my extensions and then re-enabling them corrected it for me, though I'm not sure *why* that worked or whether it completely fixed it.

Comment: Good point, I have a superuser extension

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>.

What version of Chrome are you using?